# Is there a way in the shell script that if [ <script exits with non-0 value> ] then; do <something>

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In the shell script, I want to do that 
if the shell script failed ( exited with non zero value), then before exiting the process, do something.

How could I insert such a if statement block in my shell script.

Is that feasible?

For example,

```
set -e
echo $password > confidential.txt
rm <file-that-does-not-exist>
rm confidential.txt
```

I want to make sure that the `confidential.txt` is made sure to be removed anyways

Comment: It *is* sure to be removed with your script as it's already written, unless you do something awful like run `set -e`. And that **is** awful; see the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) for some of the background that should be understood before trying to take advantage of that flag's behavior.

Comment: (BTW, `echo $password` itself is broken! Try it with `password='* foobar'`; the `*` will be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory; use `printf '%s\n' "$password"` for more robust behavior).

Comment: my bad, I intended to include the `set -e`. I just edited to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trap` with the `EXIT` pseudo signal:

```
remove_secret () {
    rm -f /path/to/confidential.txt
}
trap remove_secret EXIT
```

You probably don't want the file to remain if the script exits with 0, so `EXIT` happens regardless of the exit code.

Note that without `set -e`, `rm` on a non-existent file doesn't stop the script.

Comment: If they don't use `set -e`, this will run the function for every error, not just if the script exits with an error.

Comment: Why trap `ERR` vs `EXIT`? You want to remove the file no matter what, after all, including the case of a successful non-error exit.

Comment: True, updated. I was thinking while typing the response but didn't get back to rewrite it...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `trap` command:

```
trap 'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo failed; fi' EXIT
```

The `EXIT` trap is run when the script exits, and `$?` contains the status of the last command before it exited.

Note that a shell script's exit status is the status of the last command that it executed. So in your script, it will be the status of

```
rm confidential.txt
```

not the error from

```
rm filethatdoesnotexist
```

Unless you use `set -e` in the script, which makes it exit as soon as any command gets an error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Linux (or another operating system with `/proc/*/fd`), you have an even better option: *Delete `confidential.txt` before putting the password into it at all.*

That can look something like the following:

```
exec 3<>confidential.txt
rm -f -- confidential.txt
printf '%s\n' "$password" >&3
```

...and then, to read from that deleted file:

```
cat "/proc/$$/fd/3"  ## where $$ is the PID of the shell that ran the exec command above
```

Because the file is *already deleted*, it's guaranteed to be eligible for garbage collection by your filesystem the moment your script (or the last program it started inheriting its file descriptors) exits or is killed, even if it's killed in a way that doesn't permit traps or signal processing to take place.